# Cocoa: Create iTunes/Things like Sidebar with Xcode 4.0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Does anyone know how I can create a iTunes/Things like Sidebar with Xcode 4.0 (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uvCt.png)?
I'm pretty new to this and tried to play around with NSSplitView and NSTableView, but I've no idea how to get the "Title" (like "Erfassen" or "Fokussieren") and the Badges with the Numbers ("8" in Eingang, "4" in Heute) in it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSOutlineVIew instead of NSTableView. I suggest using a tutorial for doing this. It's pretty complicated to newbies. 
http://www.osxentwicklerforum.de/index.php?page=Thread&postID=117417&highlight=sidebar#post117417

Comment: Thanks, NSOutlineView looks good! I also found some info here to hide the triangles: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/232717-nsscrollview-like-itunes.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is another good pre-made solution:
https://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList